# Consider the polynomials $2x+3$ and $3x^2+5 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Does there exist $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $3x^2+5 = (2x+3)q(x)+r(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

Since degree of $3x^{2}+5$ is $2$ and that of $2x+3$ is $1$, if possible, let there exist $q(x)=ax+b$ and $r(x)=c$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $3x^2+5= (2x+3)q(x)+r(x)$. This implies $(3x^2+5)= (2x+3)(ax+b)+c \implies a= \frac{3}{2}, b= -\frac{9}{4}, c= \frac{47}{4}$, none of which belong to $\mathbb{Z}$. So there does not exist any such $q(x)$ and $r(x)$. Is my reason correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, assuming $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ have the implied degree restrictions of long division.

Comment: Is it required that the degree of $r$ is less than degree of $2x-3$? If so, your argument is good.

Comment: The degree to r(x) must be 0, otherwise another division by the quotient is possible.

Comment: Yes,. Simpler notice the *parity contradiction* in the lead coef of $x^2$ (LHS is odd vs. RHS even).